# SQLite query returns only '&'

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite db which has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE words (word TEXT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE lyrics (track_id, mxm_tid INT, word TEXT, count INT, is_test INT, FOREIGN KEY(word) REFERENCES words(word));
CREATE INDEX idx_lyrics1 ON lyrics ('track_id');
CREATE INDEX idx_lyrics2 ON lyrics ('mxm_tid');
CREATE INDEX idx_lyrics3 ON lyrics ('word');
CREATE INDEX idx_lyrics4 ON lyrics ('count');
CREATE INDEX idx_lyrics5 ON lyrics ('is_test');
```

I want to query the entire word column from the lyrics table. If I run:

```
SELECT * FROM lyrics;
```

This is the result:

```
TRAAAAV128F421A322|4623710|i|6|0
TRAAAAV128F421A322|4623710|the|4|0
TRAAAAV128F421A322|4623710|you|2|0
...
```

However if i run:

```
SELECT word FROM lyrics;
```

The result looks like this

```
&
&
&
...
```

I'm not too familiar with SQLite so I'm pretty confused by this behavior. As word is a foreign key I thought about having to join these tables, but as it works as long as I query everything this would be rather strange.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: provide table data on which you are fire a query.

Comment: @kishanoza - You do not trust `SELECT *`?

Comment: it is easy to identify mistake  if we have tables with data..and yaa of course i truston **select * from**

Comment: @kishanoza I'll provide whatever helps, I'm just not sure what more than a 'SELECT *' you're looking for?

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT length(word), word FROM lyrics;`?

Comment: It outputs '1|&' '1|&' and so on.